# Is this possible to use outputs from one terraform cloud workspace as variables in another workspace?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here are further details:

**Workspace-A (base stack) :** This workspace has code that will create AWS: VPC, SGs, RouteTables, Subnet and related associtions etc.

**Workspace-B (Service-1 Stack):** This workspace has code to create AWS : ALB, some ECS containers using fargate and some other components related to this service.

Now, in above case any service (Service-1, 2 , 3 etc.) wil use the VPC/base stack created by Workspace-A, how can we use outputs from Workspace A( VPC, SGs, subnets etc.) as variables of workspace-B so that workspace-B can consume those VPC and rest of the components.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this with the use of `'remote_state'` data source and to do so, you must configure a Terraform remote backend to connect to your Terraform workspaces.

Any workspace to be able to share its state must have configured a 'outputs'.

For Workspace-A, you can configure the VPC as output -

```
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "The VPC ID"
  value = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}
```

After running terraform apply with Workspace-A, configure the tf file for Workspace-B as below -

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
    organization = "org-****"
    workspaces = {
      name = "workspace-A"
    }
  }
}
```

This Terraform configuration can now access the outputs from Workspace-A as -

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.subnet_id
}
```

P.S. - I realize it's late, but it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Terraform Data Sources:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

So instead of pass outputs from one configuration to another, the best practice is to create infrastructure in Workspace-A and then query the provider to load that infrastructure in Workspace-B.

I would recommend tagging the resources created by each Workspace in your example with a unique identifier both for general traceability and also so that you can easily look up resources created by other Terraform configurations using data sources.